# ADF Pipelines stay in queue status, could we assign an alert whenever it does that?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

Triggering the email notifications when a pipeline goes to the queued state.

[image]

My current setup:

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can send status of Pipeline using Logic App.

Prerequisites

•   **Azure subscription**. If you don't have an Azure subscription, create a free account before you begin.

•   **Logic App**. To trigger sending an email from the pipeline, you use Logic Apps to define the workflow. For details on creating a Logic App workflow, see How to create a logic app.

[Create a pipeline to trigger your Logic App email workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email#create-a-pipeline-to-trigger-your-logic-app-email-workflow)

You can use system variables and expressions to make your messages dynamic. For example:

```
•   @activity("CopyData").output.errors[0].Message

•   @activity("DataFlow").error.Message
```

For more information you can also refer [link1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5718/azure-data-factory-pipeline-email-notification-part-1/) and [link2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5962/send-notifications-from-an-azure-data-factory-pipeline-part-2/)